# Django authentication with modelform

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have two models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Vendor(models.MOdel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'vendor')
    ......................................................
    ......................................................
class Customer(models.MOdel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'customer')
    ........................................................
    .......................................................
```

what i want to do is enable login for a Vendor and a customer.The login url of vendor is 'vendor/login' and customer is 'customer/login'.While a vendor submit his credentials,i want to check whether the user is a vendor or not and raise a validation error.I couldn't find a way to accomplish this using django.What i basically need is something like a modelform for User which checks the user is a vendor using a queryset.But django auth doesn't have something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Django custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), add the type field and use it as a factory source to load Vendor/Customer objects. Such solution worked for me very well. Something to start from:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

TYPES = (
    ('Vendor', 'Vendor'),
    ('Customer', 'Customer'),
)


class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPES, default='Customer')
```

This approach is very flexible and scales well if you need to add other types in the future. Small example of redirection approach:

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self, auth_user):
        self.user = auth_user

    def redirect_to(self):
        return ""

class Vendor(Base):
    def redirect_to(self):
        return "/login/vendor"

class Customer(Base):
    def redirect_to(self):
        return "/login/customer"
```

Then in the `login` view you would just dynamically create the user object:

```
auth_user = form.get_user()
cls = globals()[auth_user.type]
user = cls(auth_user)  # This will return either Vendor or Customer object
return HttpResponseRedirect(user.redirect_to())
```

You can easily create another user types by just adding new class and implementing the needed methods without even touching the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.But how could i use it for log in using django authentication ?How could i find whether its a customer trying to log in ?

Comment: Well you select user by the username/password right? Once you have the user fetched from the DB, you check the type and redirect whenever you want based on the user type. You may need to write your own `login` view for this, which should be pretty easy - just change the redirection part.

Answer (score 2):

The best strategy for me is to write two Authentication Backends, one that enables the vendor authentication and another that does it for the customer.

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS is the settings constant giving the authorization backend tuple. 
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends) can you check the documentation about authentication backends.

Declare your implentations with the settings parameter. The order counts django will try all backends untill one is successful.

Comment: wow it looks like something what i need.Need to learn it first.

Comment: Hi i wrote custom authentication backend.But the way in which authentication backends are executed( The order counts django will try all backends untill one is successful) is the problem here.I need to execute either of the backends not all.(I have created one backend for customer and one for vendor).If a customer try to log in the vendor login,he will get authenticate because both the backends run.Precisely i just want to run only vendor authentication backend when i am on the url 'vendor/login' .

Comment: There are multiple solution for that and I could give you some hints about them (they would be a bit hacky though)

But for me the main issue is with your model as it should be possible to distinguish between the two types of users only using the model (and not the url or another get or post parameter).

If it would be the case, then the first backend (let s say vender authentication backend) would try to authenticate the user among a filtered QuerySet of users having the vendor property (for instance)

Comment: yeah i did it.But the issue is i have two backends AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('backends.VendorLoginBackend','django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend') . if a customer tries to login into vendor page he will get authenticated using the second backend.what i want to do run is run "backends.VendorLoginBackend" only while trying to authenticate a vendor.